# Demarcate city areas with Google Static Maps API

Tags: google-maps, maps

I'm using [Google Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) to generate images from cities. I first tried to get only the outline of the requested city (see example 1 below), but I noticed that's not possible with google API, so I would like to demarcate the specific city, filling it's region with some color (example 2 below), but I couldn't find a way to do this with only the name of the city, because as far as I know, google requires the whole path to fill the region.

One example of request I'm trying, is this one:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=STATE+OF+SAO+PAULO&size=400x400&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:road|visibility:off&path=fillcolor:0xAA000033%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7Cenc:encoded_data
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this with this API? Or is there any better solution to get what I want?

Example 1:

[image: Region outline]

Example 2:

[image: Region demarcated]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been already asked a couple of time, currently there is no google-API that provides the data for these polygons, you'll need to use another ressource.

A good start may be osm, the [nominatim-search](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Examples) may also return these polygons. You may specify the desired format(e.g. svg or geoJson).

Using the data together with the `enc`-parameter of a static map in most cases will not work, because the url will get too long.

It's not clear what the final result should be(a kind of pictogram as in example#1 or a static map with a highligthed area as in example#2), but in both cases you may use the svg-format to draw a path.

Example:

```js
jQuery(
  function($)
  {
    $('form').submit(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('form').addClass('hidden');
      $.ajax(
        'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search',
        {
          jsonp:'json_callback',
          data:$( this ).serialize(),
          dataType:'jsonp',
          success:function(data){
        if(data.length){
        $('form').removeClass('hidden');

           $('#svg')[0].setAttribute('viewBox',[data[0].boundingbox[2],
                                               -data[0].boundingbox[1],
                                               (data[0].boundingbox[3]-data[0].boundingbox[2]),
                                               (data[0].boundingbox[1]-data[0].boundingbox[0]),
                                               ].join(' '));
          $('#svg path').attr('d',data[0].svg);
          
          
        }
          
        }
      });

    }).trigger('submit');
  }
);
```

```css
.svg{display:inline-block;border:3px solid red;background:#f1f1f1;border-radius:8px;}
       .svg svg{margin:10px;width:100px;height:100px;}
       .svg svg path{fill:red;}
       .copyright{display:block;clear:both;}
       .hidden svg,.hidden .copyright{visibility:hidden;}
       fieldset {text-align:center;}
       fieldset input{display:block;}
       fieldset input[type="submit"]{display:inline;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" name="format" value="json">
    <input type="hidden" name="polygon_svg" value="1">
    <fieldset style="float:left;">
      <input name="city"  placeholder="city" title="city" value="São Paulo"/>
      <input name="county"  placeholder="county"title="county"/>     
      <input name="state"  placeholder="state"title="state"/>
      <input name="country"  placeholder="country"title="country" value="br"/>
      <input type="submit" />
    </fieldset>
    <div class="svg">
      <svg  id="svg"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">    
        <path/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <span class="copyright">Data © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ODbL 1.0. </span>
  </form>
```

When you want to use it with a static map you may e.g. use the static map as background-image for the svg(would be more complcated, because you must calculate the correct size/position ).